# Can I get rows count by populated property in mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have questions objects like below when populate it.

```
{
   title: "Question Title",
   category: {
      "_id": "562ddc95a93f89e012554be1",
      "name": "Category",
      "parent": {
           "_id" : "562ddc95a93f89e012554be1", 
           "name": "Parent Category"
       }
   }
}
```

And category objects like below

```
{
   "_id" : "562ddc95a93f89e012554be1",
   "name": "Category Name",
   "parent": "562ddc95a93f89e012554be1"
}
```

I want get questions count which in specific parent category.

I try a query like this but it's not working.

```
Questions
   .count("category.parent._id":_id)
```

How can i do this? Is this possible in mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure your use of count like this:

```
 Questions.count({"category.parent._id" : _id}, function(err, c){
         if(err) return err;
         console.log('Count is ' + c);
 });
```

See the various possibilities in the [Docs.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count)

To test this in the mongodb shell, I created the following two documents in a collection called questions.

```
{
    "title" :"Question1",
    "category":{
        "_id":"123",
        "name" : "category 1",
        "parent" : {
            "_id" : "567",
            "name" : "parent category"
        }
    }
},
{
      "title" :"Question2",
      "category":{
          "_id":"124",
          "name" : "category 1",
          "parent" : {
              "_id" : "568",
              "name" : "parent category"
          }
      }
}
```

This query should return 1:

```
db.questions.count({"category.parent._id":"568"})
```

you should place the criteria in double quotes. It may produce an error if not used.

Comment: it's returned 0 every time

Comment: Can you open your mongodb shell and perform the query there using count()?

Comment: You can see how here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

if you have a problem with a query using mongoose. It helps if you got to the simple mongodb shell and perform queries there.

Comment: nope, result not changed. still returned 0. I'm sure result must not equal to zero.

Comment: in the mongodb shell if you run count with no criteria what does it return?

Comment: when i run without condition count query, result is 6.

Comment: See my updated answer. if it still doesn't work for you, please post your documents from mongodb shell and post your exact query from the shell.

Comment: I left from my office, i will try this tomorrow.  Thanks for your interest.